# Issues with Angular Material MatTooltip when navigating to a new route

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am supporting an Angular 10.2 application and don't know a lot about Angular but enough to get around. This application, which was developed by another entity, navigates to another component using router.navigate(compoonent). When this happens the elements with a matTooltip do not display. If I add an html element to the app.component template with a matTooltip it shows up, even with navigating to a new component. I suspect that I need to reinitialize Material to get it to scan for mapTooltip attributes and setup the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Am I  on the right track and how to I force Angular Material to initialize when a new component is loaded?

I have read about observers but I was hoping there was something simpler as there are probably 100 components.

**EDIT:**

I use the following to crate the site

```
ng new mysite
npm install @angular/material@10.2
npm install @angular/cdk@10.2
npm update
ng add @angular/material; choose css, accept the defaults

ng generate module mod1 --route mod1 --module app.module
ng generate module mod2 --route mod2 --module app.module
```

modify app.component.html

```
<h1>
    {{title}}
</h1>
<button routerLink="/mod1" matTooltip="Click here to go to module 1">Mod1</button>
<button routerLink="/mod2" matTooltip="Click here to go to module 2">Mod2</button>
<button routerLink="/" matTooltip="Click here to go to reset the modules">Reset</button>
<div style='padding-top:10px'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Modify mod1.component.html

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
    Module 1
</div>
<button matTooltip="Module 1 tooltip">Action</button>
```

modify map2.component.html

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
    Module 2
</div>
<button matTooltip="Module 2 tooltip">Action</button>
```

Modify app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule 
{ 
  constructor(router: Router)
  {
    router.resetConfig([
      { path: 'mod1', loadChildren: () => import('./mod1/mod1.module').then(m => m.Mod1Module) },
      { path: 'mod2', loadChildren: () => import('./mod2/mod2.module').then(m => m.Mod2Module) }
    ])
  }
}
```

When I run the site, I see the tooltips for the buttons in app.component.html but when I click on the module buttons I do not see the tooltip for the button.

[Image showing tooltip on app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7PEU.png)

It's hard to show the issue when the tooltip doesn't show up.

Here is my package.json, in case I missed a module

```
{
  "name": "mysite",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

thanks,
Tyson

Comment: Sounds like you're not on a good track but we'll need some code (minimum reproduction scenario) to better understand what you are saying.

Comment: `router.navigate(component)` sounds fishy - usually `navigate` is called with a route definition.

Comment: well in this instance it is 
var name = mapBase[index]; 
router.navigate([name]);
I will be mocking up an example when I get some time to work on it, nothing like getting pulled in many directions.

Comment: I added some code to the question.

Comment: @tyson I am having exact same issue did you figure out solution? matTooltip is not working on a component that is used in route